# Updating password in Mongoose with pre hook results in passport.js password check failing

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

Ive implemented a password authentication with passport and local authentication in Node.js that is as follows:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
   if (this.password) {
      this.salt =
         Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
      this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
   }
   next();
});

userSchema.methods.hashPassword = function (password) {
   return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000,
      64, 'sha512').toString('base64');
};
```

Now I added a pre hook for updating the password where I create a new salt and hash the new password. The update itself is executed, but the resulting new salt and password hash fail the password check. 
I added this code (which is a bit raw, but for now I would be happy if the concept works):

```
   userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
       if (this._update.password) {
          this.salt =
             Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
          this._update.salt = this.salt;
          this._update.password = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(this._update.password, this.salt, 10000,64,'sha512').toString('base64');
       }
       next();
    });
```

The update is done with this code:

```
  users.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.emailadres },
          {password: req.body.password}).exec();
```

I see the salt and password values being updated in the collection, but the authentication returns a failure on login after the update.
I'd expect that the update of the fields as in the above code should work. Am i missing something? Also, how is the hashPassword reusable for the update hook?

Comment: Have you tried bcrypt.js?

Comment: @AvivLo I haven't. How will this help solve this problem? Is the creation of salt values and hashing more robust?

Comment: It's more robust. The whole library is tested and wildly used. It's going to be more secure than individual custom implementation.

Comment: Accessing `this._update` directly looks more like a hack. Have you tried `this.getUpdate()` and `this.setUpdate()` ?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim thanks, The documentation on this part is not clear to me so probably I am using it wrong. I'll give it a try.